# Java 8 acceptEither CompletableFuture Example

Tags: java, java-8

I'm new to Java 8 & in the process of learning CompletableFuture API.
I also have a requirement where I need to make Asynchronous call to Third Party API & then wait for 7 seconds.
After 7 seconds, continue with my actual processing.
Also I need to check whether in these 7 seconds Async call has completed successfully. If yes then Log Success response or if Async call has completed exceptionally then Log error response in my database.

```
CompletableFure<Void> thridPartyCallFuture = Async Call to Third Party API;

//Wait for 7 seconds
```

I do not need to retrieve any response from Third Party API call, I just need to pause for 7 seconds.

And so I tried calling `thridPartyCallFuture.get(7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
but the problem with this is when I call `thridPartyCallFuture.isDone()` it will always return true, but in case if `thridPartyCallFuture` has completed exceptionally, I will not get to know, which is important to log error response in DB. Let's consider a scenario where Third Party API is down & our call had completed exceptionally. In this case `isDone()` will return `true` whereas `isCompletedExceptionally()` will return `false`.

Check if `thridPartyCallFuture` has completed successfully then Log success response in DB.

Check if `thridPartyCallFuture` has completed exceptionally then Log error response in DB.

I had tried to explore `acceptEither` but couldn't get it right.

I got to know in Java 9 a new method is introduced `orTimeOut(int)` but in Java 8 we do not have such method.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to wait 7 seconds even if the result came back sooner.
The following code shows how to handle problems with the call to the API.
And you're right, Java 9 supports timeouts much better.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    CompletableFuture<Result> completableFuture = CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(() -> {
                System.out.println("Making call to API...");
                //call API here and if call fails, throw exception
                //throw new RuntimeException("HTTP call failed");
                return new Result(true, "Done");
            })
            .handle((o, throwable) -> o.isSuccess() ? o : new Result(false, throwable.getMessage()));

    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
            .schedule(() -> {
                        Result result = completableFuture.getNow(new Result(false, "Timeout"));
                        System.out.println("Log to DB: "
                                + result.isSuccess()
                                + result.getMessage());
                        //other application method calls here
                    }, 7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

--

```
public class Result {
    private boolean success;
    private String message;

    public Result(boolean success, String message) {
        this.success = success;
        this.message = message;
    }
    //getters/setters
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kartik, this is what exactly i was looking for.
Requirement was to wait max of 7 seconds, if not process error message to DB or If I can receive the response within 7 seconds I can process success message.